# why Does my addListenerForSingleValueEvent stop reading data from Firebase database in android application?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm saving Data into Firebase Database to verify few condition I read data from database using `dataSnapshot` inside Button's click listener that I have used `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. So when I run my application and try to cick that button `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` block skip whole query. What is wrong I am not getting with code as not showing any error or crashing application. Below is my code:

```
btnCreate_Account.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String mobileverify =  phonenumber.getText().toString();
        dbuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Passanger");
        dbuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String dbmobileno = datas.child("mobileno").getValue().toString();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mobileverify)) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Please Enter Mobile No", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        if (mobileverify.equals(dbmobileno)) {
                            //Check if Same Mobile Number Registered or Not
                            phonenumber.getText().clear();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Mobile No Already Registered!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        } else if (!mobileverify.equals(mobileverify)){
                            //do something
                            btnCreate_Account.setEnabled(false);
                            AddUserRegistration();
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Please Enter New Mobile Number !!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2.FireBaseDataBase Structure
Below Image Show Database Structure
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAt4L.png

Comment: Did you specify security rules for reading database?

Comment: The first thing is to stop ignoring potential errors: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Also note that you can't simply step into `onDataChange` in the debugger, since that code is called asynchronously. If you want to see whether your `onDataChange` gets called, put a breakpoint on the first line in there: `for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {`.

Comment: yes security rule is :{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}   ,  In debugger I am getting error of 'no such instance field: 'dbuser'' and no in debugger not going into 'onDataChange' as it skips whole code block after addListner 'dbuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()' @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Did you **set a breakpoint** on the first line inside `onDataChange`? Did you implement `onCancelled` as I've shown?

Comment: Yes I set a breakpoint at first line 'onDataChange' I am retrieving data from database..while debugging i got to know there was a problem in if else condition due to which it jumps and not allowing to work button where i am checking if mobile number is stored or not **'if (mobileverify.equals(dbmobileno)) {'**  Can you help me in this how can i check and not save repeated mobilenumber? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: So is your `onDataChange` being called after all then? Because that'd mean you are getting data from Firebase, and your confusion was caused by the fact that Firebase loads data asynchronously, and you can't use the debuggers "step into" functionality to step into `onDataChange`.

Comment: Yes my `onDataChange` is being called as i am newbie i am learning how to debug so it confused me about that getting data or not thank you for your help @FrankvanPuffelen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. While the data is being loaded, the main thread continues to run the main code. Then when the data has loaded, your `onDataChanged` method is called.

All this means in this case is that you can't step into `onDataChange` with the debugger.

Let's quickly look at what this means in the debugger. I've numbered the most important lines:

```
/* 1 */    dbuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Passanger");
/* 2 */    dbuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
/* 3 */        @Override
/* 4 */        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
/* 5 */            for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
/* 6 */                String dbmobileno = datas.child("mobileno").getValue().toString();
               ...
/* 7 */        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
/* 8 */        }
/* 9 */    });
/*10 */    System.out.println("Got here");
```

I you are in the debugger which is paused on line `1`, and you tell it to go to the next statement, it will go to line `2`. So far so good, as that is probably what we'd all expect.

If you you then from line `2` tell the debugger to go to the next statement, it will jump to line `10`. The reason is that line 2 starts an asynchronous operation, which will take some time to complete. So the debugger continues with the statement *after* the asynchronous helper class, which is at line `10`.

If you want to see if `onDataChange` gets called, you need to set a breakpoint on the first line inside of that method, so line `5` in this case. Once the debugger hits that breakpoint, you can continue stepping through that method with the usual "next statement" instruction.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to understand easily as you explained in a very simple way.